# Array of an Interface

Tags: java, constructor, interface

I have an interface ***Register***.

```
public interface Register extends InputRegister {
  void setValue(int paramInt);

  void setValue(short paramShort);

  void setValue(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte);
  }
```

And one class which contains a constructor **WriteMultipleRegistersRequest** and importing the Register interface.

```
public WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(int first, Register[] registers)
```

These clas**strong text**ses and **interfaces** are available into a jar. I have a float number which I converted into byte[] array. Now, I want to **pass byte[] array** through **WriteMultipleRegistersRequest()** constructor as an argument.
 Suggest me some way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have an Apple[], suggest how to convert it to an Orange[]

Comment: You need to properly define what you want to happen to your byte array when you create that class and give it that byte array.

Comment: The explanation needs to go deeper. What is this class supposed to do with the registers? The interface indicates that it *writes* into the registers, and doesn't *read* from them. So the value you have is not going to be read. What is the task you are supposed to be doing with it? What other methods does it have?

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but I'm assuming that you just want the `WriteMultipleRegistersRequest` to operate on a single `Register` which represents the byte array.

In any case, you need to create a class which implements `Register`:

```
class SimpleRegister implements Register {
   ...
}
```

You'll probably initialize a new instance and set the byte array, then call the function:

```
SimpleRegister s = new SimpleRegister();
s.setValue(byteArr);
Register[] registerArr = new Register[1];
registerArr[0] = s;
WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(someInt, registerArr);
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you can call `setValue(byteArrayInput)` to convert your byte array to a `Register` instance. Since Register is an interface, you need an implementation for it:

```java
class RegisterImplementation implements Register {
  void setValue(int paramInt) { /* do something with the value */ }

  void setValue(short paramShort) { /* do something with the value */ }

  void setValue(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte) {
    // do something with the value. e.g. convert or parse it
  }
}

byte[] byteArray = …;
Register register = new RegisterImplementation();
register.setValue(byteArray);
Register[] registers = { register };
WriteMultipleRegisterRequests(…, registers);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. You are right, I missed that. You need an implementation of the interface. Will update